# Convert Symbology to Representation in arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, symbology, arcgis-10.6, representation

I know in ArcMap 10.6, there is feature called : "Convert Symbology to Representation" which one can execute by right clicking on a feature class  in Table Of Contents.
I like to know how to Convert Symbology to Representation, in a Python script tool using ArcPy library. Basically I like to do it in a script automatically rather than manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is far from everything in the ArcMap GUI that has been made accessible via ArcPy.

If there were a geoprocessing tool available to convert symbology to representations then I would expect that it would be found in the page titled [An overview of the Representation Management toolset](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/cartography-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-representation-management-tools.htm).

However, there is no tool there that corresponds to the functionality that you seek.